# Remove empty element from array

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting values as input and pushing them as an Array to the back end. There are 6 predefined items in the Array in the front end. If I send 6 values there won't be any empty elements inside the array. If I send less than 6 it's creating an empty element. That's a known fact. Now I want to filter out the empty elements before pushing the array.

**Actual output**

```
[
    {

        "ABC_Info": {
            "_id": "5c404e2d16e42513905189a1",
            "ABC": [
                {
                    "_id": "5c404e2d16e42513905189a7",
                    "a": "Dosa",
                    "b": 15,
                    "c": 30
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5c404e2d16e42513905189a6",
                    "a": "Idly",
                    "b": 25,
                    "b": 25
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5c404e2d16e42513905189a5",
                    "a": "Vada",
                    "b": 25,
                    "c": 35
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5c404e2d16e42513905189a4"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5c404e2d16e42513905189a3"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5c404e2d16e42513905189a2"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

**TS**

```
this.abcService.addabc(ABC).subscribe(
    res => {
        this.abcArray.push(res); //abcArray is a array. Before Pushing  I want to check for empty element and remove before pushing

    },
    error => console.log(error)
);
}
```

Comment: Does empty mean property a, b and c is not set?

Comment: yes if a, b and c is not set

Comment: I have one question, what do you want to filter before pushing, do you want to check for `res` object and validate and push only if it is valid. Or you want to filter `this.abcArray` and push in filtered array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter method and filter array based on property count in each item like follows

```
this.abcService.addabc(ABC).subscribe(
    res => {
        let res1 = res.filter(i=>Object.keys(i.ABC_Info.ABC).length >1);
        this.abcArray.push(res1); //abcArray is a array. Before Pushing  I want to check for empty element and remove before pushing

    },
    error => console.log(error)
);
}
```

filter array element without any property like _id you can use

```
res.filter(i=>Object.keys(i.ABC_Info.ABC).length >0);
```

Comment: but this taking off my object names

Comment: you could try this way res.filter(i=>Object.keys(i.ABC_Info.ABC).length >1);

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter) on your array if you'd like to make it after you have the data:

```
this.abcArray.filter(item => ...your predicate to say an item is non-empty...)
```

If you can control when the items are pushed or not, why don't you simply push them just when you know they are non-empty?

```
if (... your predicate non empty ...)
  this.abcArray.push(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to know if the object is empty besides the `_id` property, so you can do something like this:

```
res.ABC.filter(obj => {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  return (keys.length !== 1  || keys[0] !== '_id') && keys.length !== 0;
});
```

Comment: thanks. I could get empty objects that besides _id. How to remove that and push only those with values

Answer (score 1):

You can use array filter :

```
this.abcArray = res.ABC.filter(result => result.a && result.b && result.c);
```